# GWT Window onBlur

Tags: gwt, onblur, onfocus

how can a GWT app determine if the browser window or tab loses focus i.e. gets inactive? I need this to switch a canvas based application into pause state, but only when the whole browser gets inactive. How can this be done? Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such ready implementation for Window onblur.You have to write on your own

```
private native static void initialize() /*-{
$wnd.onblur = new function( e ) {
@packagepath.WindowEventManager::getInstance()().notifyOnBlur( e );
}
```

See this for [full implementation.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/HJxYq-dA1k0)

Comment: Just finding this now, but please note that the function should be wrapped with `$entry(...)`, and probably doesn't need a `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that worked for me:

```java
    private native void listenForBlur(MyClass instance) /*-{
        $wnd.addEventListener('blur', function() {
            instance.@com.blah.foo.MyClass::handleFocusLost()();
        });

    }-*/;


    private void handleFocusLost() {
       // do something
    }
```

I then call the function as follows:

```java
listenForBlur(this);
```